# Calculate Transaction Amount sum for all account numbers from the current date to past 10 days

Tags: sql

My table has the following columns:

```
Account_number | Transaction_Date | Transaction | Amount
```

Would someone be able to help me with a SQL query where I can calculate the total transaction amount from the current date to past 10 days for each account.

Comment: Welcome to SO. `SELECT account_number, SUM(Transaction_Amount) AS total_transaction_amount FROM table WHERE transaction_date > SYSDATE - 10 GROUP BY account_number` Depending on RDBMS you may need to change `WHERE` part  and/or handle time part(if applicable)

Comment: Sorry I mistyped. Calculate the total transaction amount from the transaction date to past 10 days. (if the same account number has transacted in the past 10 days it should show the account number and the total transaction amount for past 10 days from the transaction date)

Comment: Then you have to add another column to GROUP BY: `SELECT account_number, TRUNC(transaction_date), SUM(Transaction_Amount) AS total_transaction_amount FROM table WHERE transaction_date > SYSDATE - 10 GROUP BY account_number, TRUNC(transaction_date)` Warning. If there wasn't any transaction per day and account you wouldn't get a row with a `0` value.

Comment: Thank you. Will try this out.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT account_number,
       SUM(Transaction_Amount)
FROM table
WHERE transaction_date between DATEADD(Day,-10,getdate()) and getdate()
GROUP BY account_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's SQL-Server solution:

```
select sum([Transaction]) from MY_TABLE
where Transaction_Date > DATEADD(Day,-10,getdate())
```

MySql

```
select sum(Transaction) from MY_TABLE
where Transaction_Date > date_add(now(), interval -10 day)
```

Oracle

```
select sum(Transaction) from MY_TABLE
where Transaction_Date > SYSDATE - interval '-10' day
```